# SIGABRT when calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

In an app, I'm pulling a JSON array and using it to populate a UITableView:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, NSURLConnectionDelegate {
    var tableData: [AnyObject] = []
    // ...

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        var dataAsString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var err: NSError

        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        // After parsing JSON...
        tableData += json as Array
        tableView.reloadData()

        tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(index: tableData.count - 1), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)
    }

    // ...
}
```

The final line, calling `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`, causes a signal SIGABRT. Commenting out the line fixes it. I'm fairly new to iOS development so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following code:

```
NSIndexPath(forRow: tableData.count - 1, inSection: 0) //O in section: if tableView has only one section
```

instead of:

```
NSIndexPath(index: tableData.count - 1)
```

Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.

Answer (score 0):

You never checked to see if the data has any data in it before scrollToRowAtIndexPath. It may be empty in which case tableData.count -1 = -1

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried wrapping the call in a conditional `if tableData.count > 0 {...}` but still had the same problem.

Comment: Check the tableview initialization.. It may be nil

Comment: It looks okay. I call reloadData on the tableView right above it